# Product Subtotal Price is more than the Product Unit Price

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Hi!

We have setup magento with 3 Currency options - USD, IDR & INR and the checkout payment goes to paypal, however the price of the products get increased for IDR & INR while with USD the product price remains the same. Below are 3 screenshots to help us understand the difference in product price in Units and in SubTotal in the View Cart page and on checkout.

http://postimg.org/gallery/q8rxvqqa/

Base Currency & Default Display Currency is USD.

No Tax has been setup yet.

No Shipping settings/method has been setup yet.

Webservicex is used to manage the currency rates.

As you can see the Price is in subtotal gets increased from that of the price in units.

Would you help us with the reason why this is happening and how can we resolve it.

Thanks,

Nitesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. There were some rules by default under sales --》tax --》Manage Tax & Manage Tax Zone & Rates.

Once those rules were deleted the price in view cart were the same for unit price and subtotal and worked in all 3 currencies.